# Running a LocalReport with a remote SSRS DataSource in ASP.NET ReportViewer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'll try to describe what exactly I am doing:
I am trying to incorporate a **ReportViewer** control into my **ASP.NET** page, that would enable the user to view pre-defined and useruploaded, RDL reports, set parameters and finally receive the output (both on-screen and in a file).

So we have an **SSRS** on a remote server, with shared datasources defined there. The remote server also has the **OLAP cube** on it, that stores the data for the datasource.

**Question:** What puzzles me is how do you provide the connection between a local report and the remote datasource to let the report execute it's **mdx query**?

So far I was only able to display LocalReport with local datasource, and wasn't able to DISPLAY the ServerReport at all (just receiving the resulting bytes from the server).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can solve your problem if you will deploy LocalReports to
   that Remote Server in some separate sub-folder. Then you will be
   able to use Shared Datasource.
2. ReportViewer has [ProcessingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.processingmode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property Local or Remote. It
   could be used for both. You can add 2 instances of ReportViewer on
   the page one for Local and one for Remote reports.

Comment: So you're saying I can't use a shared datasource remotely?
I need to be able to view that report in the page, and be able to export it into a file.

As I've described, currently I can either use the LocalReport and feed it dataset or use ServerReport and receive exported file out.